# Invalid postback or callback argument when posting a form from a directory

Tags: asp.net, iis

Here's my folder structure for my website

```
www.website.com
│   default.aspx
│   web.config    
│   registration_test.aspx
|
└───Registration
│   │   default.aspx
|   |   ...
...
```

If I go to https://www.website.com/Registration it shows a form to submit, it simply saves to a database and sends an e-mail.  But when I do it from this page I get the `Invalid postback or callback argument` error even if I add `<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>`.  But I made an exact copy of this page to registration_test.aspx and it works perfectly fine here.

The weird thing is when I submit the form on https://www.website.com/Registration, after it errors out the URL in my browser changes to https://www.website.com/default.aspx instead, looks like it's trying to POST to this url possibly.  What's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the form action to point to the directory.  Had to do this programatically since every page shares the same form

```
form1.Action = "/Registration/default.aspx"
```